# Intl extension in IIS moodle

Tags: php, apache, iis-7, moodle, intl

I am trying to install intl extension in moodle which is a php application. I've added the lines

```
extension = php_intl.dll 
and 
[intl]
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

in my php.ini file. When I do this in apache and copy all the icuu*.dll files in apache/bin folder, I can see the extension in the application. In IIS server, I don't know where to copy the icuu*.dll files and whether I need to copy those files. If I restart without copying, the application still runs but I can't see the extension. Can someone please advise me?

Comment: Copy the files to the `<WINDOWS>\SYSTEM32` directory

Comment: I copied them to system32 directory but the application still can't read the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to disable php_wincache.dll extension and it worked. Then i could reenable it again.
I used VC9 x86 Thread Safe intl extension dll from zip package from here http://windows.php.net/download/